# How to get number of followers using Tweepy in a specific date?

Tags: tweepy

I would like to know if exists any way to get the number of followers of an account using Tweepy (or with raw Twitter API) in a specific date. 
I've been watching out to several ways to do this without success. Now I'm saving this number every day to can build a special graphics but I would like to do this with old accounts to know their growth.

I've seen this kind of histograms in some apps and tools, because of this I think that this is possible but I don´t find how.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Historical activity doesn't seem to be publicly available, outside of services like [Gnip](https://gnip.com). Tweepy allows you to check for the existence of a follower relationship with `API.exists_friendship(user_a, user_b)`, and you may be able to get some more information with `API.show_friendship(user_a, user_b)`.